# How to install py.test on Windows

Tags: python

I am following the instructions on - http://pytest.org/latest/getting-started.html#installation-issues.

I have tried many options and also searched on the web. But I still get the following errors.

```
Installed c:\python26\lib\site-packages\pytest-2.2.3-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for pytest==2.2.3
Searching for py>=1.4.7.dev2
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/py/
Download error: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'py' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for py>=1.4.7.dev2
Best match: None
```

I have Windows XP and python 2.6. I want to install py.test on this settings. Is there a way for this to work?

Comment: the problem is with the "getaddrinfo failed" part. see the second answer here: stackoverflow.com/questions/1290142/python-urllib2-problem

Answer (score 3):

from you instruction:

Windows: If “easy_install” or “py.test” are not found you need to **add the Python script path to your PATH**, see here: Python for Windows. You may alternatively use an ActivePython install which does this for you automatically.

[How to set PATH variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)